# Horizontally align pgf plots with y-axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to horizontally align my two graphs, so that the y-axes are aligned. The problem is that the one y-axis has double digits and the other has single digits as the units.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{tikz, color}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12, width=12cm}

\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines = left, xmin=0, ymin=0]
\addplot [domain=0:80]
    {0.001*x^3-0.09*x^2+2.95*x}
    ;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines = left, xmin=0, ymin=0]
\addplot [domain=0:80]
    {0.001*x^2-0.09*x+2.95}
    ;
\addplot [domain=0:80]
    {0.003*x^2-0.18*x+2.95}
    ;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `$\ \, $` does the trick, but I want a proper method.

Comment: You could also have a look at the `groupplots` library of `pgfplots`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is using option `trim axis left` for both `tikzpicture` environments:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12, width=12cm}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document} 
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left]
\begin{axis}[axis lines = left, xmin=0, ymin=0]
\addplot [domain=0:80]
    {0.001*x^3-0.09*x^2+2.95*x}
    ;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left]
\begin{axis}[axis lines = left, xmin=0, ymin=0]
\addplot [domain=0:80]
    {0.001*x^2-0.09*x+2.95}
    ;
\addplot [domain=0:80]
    {0.003*x^2-0.18*x+2.95}
    ;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```